# Read cheetah-templated YAML files in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, yaml

In my C# application I am trying to read YAML files that are produced in Python using [Cheetah template](https://cheetahtemplate.org). The YAML files look like:

```
{% set name = "a_name" %}
{% set version = "1.2" %}

package:
  name: {{ name|lower }}
  version: {{ version }}

source:
  url: https://a_website.com/{{ version }}.tar.gz
```

Here is how I try to parse it:

```cs
using YamlDotNet.RepresentationModel;

using var reader = new StreamReader(yaml_filename);
var yaml = new YamlStream();
yaml.Load(reader);
```

Using this code I get error as the following:

> found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 1 column 2

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are trying to read a cheetah template, not the result of running the cheetah against that file.

If you check the file with a validator you get the error:

```
YAMLException: missed comma between flow collection entries at line 1,
column 2:
    {% set name = "a_name" %}
     ^
```

Assuming that % relates to cheetah then the solution is first run cheetah against that file and after that load it.

Presuming that if you run cheetah againt that file the end result should be what is an valid yaml file and should be able to load correctly.

```
package:
  name: a_name
  version: 1.2

source:
  url: https://a_website.com/1.2.tar.gz
```

Comment: As I have mentioned for the other answer, modifying the input according to the project setup is not an option.

Comment: How would something like yaml.Load(parseCheetah(yamlfilecontainingnonyamlspecstuff)); be against the project setup.

Comment: I don't see an implementation of `parseCheetah`; do you mean I should write a cheetah parser myself?!

Comment: No.. that was just pseudo code. either find a cheetah #c library, install the cheetah python binaries and invoke it from c#.. or ask the yaml supplier to send you the data pre parsed.

Comment: Or one could setup a simple python rest service for the parsing the yaml before doing what ever you want with C#. Not sure what’s the most feasible for you to implement

Answer (score 0):

This is currently an error message they are looking at replacing with a more helpful one:

Tabs are not allowed for indentation in the YAML.

Comment: Found [here](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/issues/288).